# How do I implement this random number generator above every comment in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, random

I have a random number generator here, but I can't get it working above all WordPress comments. I get:

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class Random in [mysite]/functions.php on line 148
```

Here is the function for the random number generator:

```
/**
 * Generate random images for the forum games function
 */
function random_forum_games() {

class Random {
    // random seed
    private static $RSeed = 0;

    // set seed
    public static function seed($s = 0) {
        self::$RSeed = abs(intval($s)) % 9999999 + 1;
        self::num();
    }

    // generate random number
    public static function num($min = 0, $max = 9999999) {
        if (self::$RSeed == 0) self::seed(mt_rand());
        self::$RSeed = (self::$RSeed * 125) % 2796203;
        return self::$RSeed % ($max - $min + 1) + $min;
    }
}

    // set seed
    Random::seed(42);
    // echo 10 numbers between 1 and 10
    for ($i = 0; $i < 1; $i++) {
        echo Random::num(1, 10) . '<br />';
    }
}
add_action( 'forum_games', 'random_forum_games'  );
```

In order to call the function above every comment, in my comments template, I have:

```
<?php do_action ( 'forum_games' ); ?>
```

I know why what I am doing is wrong, but I am not really a "programmer". I came here for a little bit of simple help, whether it be a single line of code or a link to something that can tell me what to do without trying to teach me PHP. I do not have time to learn PHP, so please be kind. If there is not a simple solution, then you don't have to answer.

I don't mean to sound defensive, but I have been turned away by programmers before. Not everyone who needs to get something running has the time or skill to learn every single detail. You don't expect every person who prepares a meal for their family to learn how to hunt or to make pesticides, so please do not turn me away just because I cannot do PHP. If you want, just link me to something that isn't trying to teach me to code from scratch. I am doing as much of the work myself as I can, and I'm asking only for tidbits of support, so please don't be rude. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You do not define a class inside a function. It should be defined OUTSIDE of the function, and then you can (if need be) **INSTANTIATE** it inside the function, e.g.

```
class rand {
   ...
}

function get_rand() {
    $r = new rand();
}
```

or better yet, you would simply have a get_rand() method inside the class:

```
class rand() {
   function get_rand() {
      ...
   }
}

$r = new rand();
echo $r->get_rand();
```

Answer (score 1):

it seems like you declared the function more than once. Maybe it is included more than once or you are calling the class more than once. Try moving the class out of the function and if it is in an include file, include it only once with include_once rather than include.

As for people not being friendly... some are, so what. Most are friendly, helpful... just make sure you give details about your problem (code + way to make it repeatable) and show you made an effort, you'll be fine :)

Comment: I got it working. Now I just need to figure out how to make it be a different number for each comment! Thanks!

Comment: if all you need is a random number, the standard php function rand($minValue,$maxValue) will always return a different number  without the hassle of a class;

Comment: Youn Elan - No-- I need the number to be constant among all visitors and page refreshes. For example, a "5" shows up as "5" to everyone, every visit.

Comment: maybe have a custom field in the comment. Depending on what you are trying to do, may require a plugin or not. You could alternatively maybe try to md5 the number